24.04 LTS update went awry
I just updated from 24.04 to 24.04 LTS. Everything seemed to go fine. But after I finished,

The desktop did not come up on boot -- instead I got a terminal for login.
The inetd daemon seemed to work fine: I had no trouble logging in via telnet.
It doesn't know about my network-attached printer.
Apache works half-way: it delvers my home screen to my PC but can't find my cgi-bin.
All my files and stuff seem to be there, but all I've got is a raw Linux machine. It's like it decided to quit half-way through.

Any ideas what I can try next?

You could review /var/log/apt/term.log for error messages.
